# How to resize the tbody of html table vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, resize, fixed-header-tables

I have a `HTML table` with fixed header.

So, `thead` is `fixed` and `tbody` is `scrollable`.

Now, I want to resize the `table height(vertical only)` by grabbing the bottom of the `tbody`(like applying `resize` attribute to `textarea`) ,so we can see more data at a time.

Comment: Please read **[how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** and then edit the question

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/resizable/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by using a little bit of css, it's very simple. Here's the part to resize the tbody verticaly;

Add an ID to your tbody (`<tbody id="tbody">`) for example. Here's the CSS;

```
#tbody {
height: 500px; (a very tall tbody)
}
```

or a small one;

```
#tbody {
height: 100px;
}
```

I hope I helped you out!

Comment: Hi,i want to resize the table dynamically by pulling the bottom of the table.
eg: like using jquery resizable api

Comment: Hi, I don't use the resizable much, but here's a good explanation and how to use them: http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/. Good luck, and I hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it using jquery then do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#your_table_id").css('height','250px');
 });
```

or

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#your_table_id").height($("#your_height_equal").height());
 });
```

The second method is for making the height equal to another table or div etc.

Answer (score 0):

**I think you are looking for something like this**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <style>
  #window {
      width: 500px;
      height: 400px;
      min-width: 100px;
      min-height: 100px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  }
  #header {
      height: 25px;
      line-height: 25px;
      background-color: gray;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
  }
  table {
      min-height: 300px;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  #tableContainer {
      position: absolute;
      top: 25px;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: auto;
  }
  td {
      padding: 5px;
      margin: 0px;
      border: 1px solid gray;
  }
  tr:last-child td {
      border-bottom: none;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="window">
      <div id="header">Draggable Header</div>
      <div id="tableContainer">
          <table>
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <td>Column 1</td>
                      <td>Column 2</td>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                  <tr>
                      <td>Data 1</td>
                      <td>Data 2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>Data 1</td>
                      <td>Data 2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>Data 1</td>
                      <td>Data 2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>Data 1</td>
                      <td>Data 2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>Data 1</td>
                      <td>Data 2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>Data 1</td>
                      <td>Data 2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>Data 1</td>
                      <td>Data 2</td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
  </div>

<script>

  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#window').draggable();
      $('#window').resizable();
  });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,but my aim is not like this.Now it resizing the whole table.
My table is scrollable.
My aim is : if i pull from table bottom only, then the  rest of data should be shown.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve then ?

Comment: Please go through the link below
http://s21.postimg.org/rt2t8shs7/table.jpg
This is what am looking for.

Comment: are you wanting resizable rows and column?

Comment: No,i don't want to resize the row and column.i just to want to drag the table bottom and want to see the rest of data.